# How to calculate the crossing surface area of two functions

Tags: functions, circles, area

The circle is
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1,$$and the following functions are given:
$$y = -1,\quad y= -x$$as shown in the image below. I need to calculate the crossing surface area of the functions (highlighted part in the image) when $x < 0.$

I have the following equation for solving the problem but I'm not sure if it's correct for this case or not:
$$S(G) = ∫_a^b(f_2(x)-f_1(x))dx.$$
Can you help with it?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4JDN.png)

Comment: You did not draw the line $y=-1$ but the line $x=-1.$ Besides, the surface you are interested in is not clear at all. Can you please define it with inequalities? (like $x<0,$ $x^2+y^2>1$ or $<1$, and so on).

Comment: The surface I mentioned is the highlighted part in the image if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: The image I provided is the task. y= -1 is one of the two functions as it is shown in the image. Is it the 'y = -1' part that is wrong?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that part. If we assume that I want to calculate the crossing surface are of those two functions (the one you mentioned and y = -x).Is it correct to use the equation written above?

Comment: Your formula $S(G)=\dots$ is correct provided you recall the hypothesis (how $G$ is defined with *inequalities* involving $f_1,f_2$), and in order to apply it: again, *define your surface with inequalities* (so that you discover to which $f_1,f_2$ you must apply your formula, and between which limits).

Comment: I could't include the limits because of the formatting, but those are a and b which I don't think change something. I think the issue is with the task itself as the image is the only information i have. Thanks anyway

Comment: You have to find out $a,b$ from this image. I.e. between which values does $x$ vary when $(x,y)$ belongs to your surface. Obviously $a=-1.$ Now calculate $b.$

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: thanks. and the last question. is it possible for the result to be 0?

Comment: No: look at your image. The area of such a "non-thin" surface is not $0.$ What functions $f_1,f_2$ and what limit $b$ did you find?